# Click on the same element but need different variables/value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a calculator and every time I click on different div with the same class, I'd like to be able to get different values too. For example,

```
$('.numbers').click(function () {
    $('#result').append('<span class ="append">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');
    a = +$('.append').text();
});
```

I wanna do the same but getting different value so I can set it as var b.

Right now, I'm getting the same value showing up twice. Any idea?

My working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4jxvxub/5/)

Also, right now, whenever I click on number 1, it didn't convert to a number for some reason. Other numbers are fine though.

Updated.

Is there anyone smart enough to help me out with this?! I don't want to do array first off. Second off, I know why it shows double the number. I'd like it to stop at the first click, save that value to var a. Then second click will show new value and save it to var b.

Here's one that doesn't need to do array.

https://github.com/meherchandan/Calculator/blob/master/calculator.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working as a normal calculator:
http://jsfiddle.net/y4jxvxub/45/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var number=0, buffer="", result=0, operator="";
    
    $('.numbers').click(function () {
        $('#result').text($('#result').text() + $(this).text());
        buffer = buffer + $(this).text();
    });

    $('.operators').click(function () {

        number = parseFloat(buffer);
        buffer = "";

        switch (operator) {
            case '+':
                number = result + number;
                break;
            case '-':
                number = result - number;
                break;
            case 'x':
                number = result * number;
                break;
            case '÷':
                number = result / number;
                break;
        }
        operator = $(this).text();     
        result = number;
        
        $('#result').text($('#result').text() + operator);
        if ($(this).text()=='=') {
            buffer = result;
            $('#result').text(result);
        }
    });

    $('#clear').click(function () {
        number=0, buffer="", result=0, operator="";
        $('#result').text("");
    });
});
```

Comment: WORK! I suggest though to not append fully the equation on the result because people will get confused as a+b*c should start at * not +. THANKS!!!

Comment: Hi i am aware of this, and this requires more complicated code to handle, therefore I have left out the Order Of Operation. example a more complicated expression:
1+2*3-4/5, people would assume 1+(2*3)-(4/5)
but it could also mean ((1+2*3)-4)/5
and any other combinations.

To handle this correctly you will need to construct a parse tree for the expression and evaluate it from there. That way you can easily control which operator should be done first etc...

Answer (score 1):

Forget my previous answer. The problem is that you have two identical functions. Delete the first one.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4jxvxub/9/

Example:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        $('.numbers').click(function () {
            $('#result').append('<span class ="append">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');
            a = +$('.append').text();
    
        });
        
        $('.operators').click(function () {
            switch ($(this).text()) {
                case '+':
                    result = a + b;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result = a - b;
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    result = a * b;
                    break;
                case '÷':
                    result = a / b;
                    break;
                case '=':
                    $('.append').remove();
                    $('#result').append('<span class="append">' + result + '</span>');
            }
        });
        $('#clear').click(function () {
            $('.append').remove();
        });
    });
```

```css
.head {
    height: 125px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #9e532a;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #63341a;
}
.eyes {
    height: 20px;
    width: 13px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
.ears {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #9e532a;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #63341a;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
.left_ear {
    left: -20px;
}
.left_ear:after {
    content:"";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.right_ear:after {
    content:"";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.right_ear {
    right: -20px;
}
.right_eye {
    right: 30px
}
.left_eye {
    left: 30px;
}
.nose {
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 49px;
    border-radius: 60%;
}
.nose_bridge {
    height: 15px;
    width: 3px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 13px;
}
.mouth {
    width: 60px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 33px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
.body {
    height: 450px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: -85px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.head:before {
    content:"";
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: -130px;
}
.body:after {
    content:"";
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
}
.body:before {
    content:"";
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
}
#result {
    height: 50px;
    width: 248px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 25px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px black;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#calculator {
    width: 248px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 24px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.numbers {
    width: 61px;
    height: 62px;
    background: #D8D6D6;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 62px;
}
.numbers:hover {
    background: #DDD2BE;
}
.operators {
    background: #F27B17;
    width: 61px;
    height: 62px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 62px;
}
.operators:hover {
    background: orange;
}
/*#split {
  width: 61px;
  height: 62px;
  background: #D8D6D6;
  border-right: 1px  solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px  solid black;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 62px;
}
 .append {
    float: right;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="left_ear ears"></div>
            <div class="right_ear ears"></div>
            <div class="left_eye eyes"></div>
            <div class="right_eye eyes"></div>
            <div class="nose">
                <div class="nose_bridge"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mouth"></div>
            <div class="body">
                <div id="result"></div>
                <div id="calculator">
                    <div class="numbers" id="n1"><span>1</span>

                    </div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n2">2</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n3">3</div>
                    <div class="operators" id="add">+</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n4">4</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n5">5</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n6">6</div>
                    <div class="operators" id="minus">-</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n7">7</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n8">8</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n9">9</div>
                    <div class="operators" id="multiply">x</div>
                    <div class="numbers" style="width: 123px" id="n0">0</div>
                    <div class="numbers split">.</div>
                    <div class="operators" id="divide">÷</div>
                    <div class="numbers" style="width:185px" id="clear">CLEAR</div>
                    <div class="operators equal">=</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not really working :(. Should the e be written in full as event btw? Sry i'm still new to jquery...Thanks

Comment: You just deleted the b? There's no var b to go into the equation... :(

Comment: that's why you are receiving two equal numbers in the output, because you are append a and b. And when you click in some number, the a will be the same number as b. You need change your logic.

Comment: Okie I was hoping there's a way around it. Thanks thou

Comment: really this is not the right way to do a calculator, you need use arrays like @vineeth said. Sorry not help the way you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/y4jxvxub/11/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a ;
    var b ;
    var result;
    $('.numbers').click(function () {
        $('#result').append('<span class ="append">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');
        if(a==undefined){
            a = parseInt($(this).text());
        } else {
            b = parseInt($(this).text());
        }
    });

    $('.operators').click(function () {
        switch ($(this).text()) {
            case '+':
                result = a + b;
                break;
            case '-':
                result = a - b;
                break;
            case 'x':
                result = a * b;
                break;
            case '÷':
                result = a / b;
                break;
            case '=':
                 $('.append').remove();
                $('#result').append('<span class="append">' + result + '</span>');
        }
    });
    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('.append').remove();
    });
});
```

You can try this a small change in your code. You have to select the 2 single digit numbers first and then the operator and then "=".

Answer (score 0):

working code without array, I tweaked your code a bit, since `<span class="append"></span>` is not necessary.
http://jsfiddle.net/y4jxvxub/15/

Comment: the code allows you to perform operations on multi-digit numbers, so if you only want single-digit number, please refer to the below answer

Answer (score 0):

My little tweak, this is only good for simple math operations ... you need to spend more time for complex case like: 1 + 3 + 3 ....
Hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.screen = $('#result');
    
    var a,c;
    $('.numbers').click(function () {
        $('#result').append('<span class ="append">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');
        b = +$('.append').text();        
    });
   
    $('.operators').click(function () {
        switch ($(this).text()) {
            case '+':
                operator='+';
                a = parseInt(b);
                $.screen.text('');  
                break;
            case '-':
                operator='-';
                a = parseInt(b);
                $.screen.text('');  
                break;
            case 'x':
                operator='*';
                a = parseInt(b);
                $.screen.text('');  
                break;
            case '÷':
                operator='/';
                a = parseInt(b);
                $.screen.text('');  
                break;
            case '=':
                c= parseInt(b);
                $.screen.text(''); 
                if(operator=='+'){
                    $.screen.text(a+c);
                }else if(operator=='-'){
                    $.screen.text(a-c);
                }else if(operator=='*'){
                    $.screen.text(a*c);
                }else if(operator=='/'){
                    $.screen.text(a/c);                 
                }
                
        }
    });
    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('#result').empty();
            
    });
});
```

```css
.head {
    height: 125px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #9e532a;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #63341a;
}
.eyes {
    height: 20px;
    width: 13px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
.ears {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #9e532a;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #63341a;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
.left_ear {
    left: -20px;
}
.left_ear:after {
    content:"";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.right_ear:after {
    content:"";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.right_ear {
    right: -20px;
}
.right_eye {
    right: 30px
}
.left_eye {
    left: 30px;
}
.nose {
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 49px;
    border-radius: 60%;
}
.nose_bridge {
    height: 15px;
    width: 3px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 13px;
}
.mouth {
    width: 60px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 33px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
.body {
    height: 450px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: -85px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.head:before {
    content:"";
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: -130px;
}
.body:after {
    content:"";
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
}
.body:before {
    content:"";
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #63341a;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
}
#result {
    height: 50px;
    width: 248px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 25px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px black;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#calculator {
    width: 248px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 24px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.numbers {
    width: 61px;
    height: 62px;
    background: #D8D6D6;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 62px;
}
.numbers:hover {
    background: #DDD2BE;
}
.operators {
    background: #F27B17;
    width: 61px;
    height: 62px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 62px;
}
.operators:hover {
    background: orange;
}
/*#split {
  width: 61px;
  height: 62px;
  background: #D8D6D6;
  border-right: 1px  solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px  solid black;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 62px;
}
 .append {
    float: right;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="left_ear ears"></div>
            <div class="right_ear ears"></div>
            <div class="left_eye eyes"></div>
            <div class="right_eye eyes"></div>
            <div class="nose">
                <div class="nose_bridge"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mouth"></div>
            <div class="body">
                <div id="result"></div>
                <div id="calculator">
                    <div class="numbers" id="n1">1</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n2">2</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n3">3</div>
                    <div class="operators" id="add">+</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n4">4</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n5">5</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n6">6</div>
                    <div class="operators" id="minus">-</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n7">7</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n8">8</div>
                    <div class="numbers" id="n9">9</div>
                    <div class="operators" id="multiply">x</div>
                    <div class="numbers" style="width: 123px" id="n0">0</div>
                    <div class="numbers split">.</div>
                    <div class="operators" id="divide">÷</div>
                    <div class="numbers" style="width:185px" id="clear">CLEAR</div>
                    <div class="operators equal">=</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I did think about that. If you want to add a+b+c...I think you can take the text() of the append at last then assign or update it to variable a then you get new var b and so on. Not too sure how it'll turn out yet though.